# How to use Netsh wlan when SSID contains whitespace?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, cmd.exe, netsh

I cannot use **netsh WLAN** command when the network I am trying to work with contains whitespace. For eg: While working with a network with SSID "**Some Network"**

```
C:\Users\Padmanava>netsh wlan show profile Some Network key=clear
There is no such wireless interface on the system.
```

But when working with a network with SSID "**SomeNetwork**"
It works perfectly fine

```
C:\Users\Padmanava>netsh wlan show profile Lenovo key=clear

Profile Lenovo on interface Wi-Fi 2:
=======================================================================

Applied: All User Profile

Profile information
-------------------
    Version                : 1
    Type                   : Wireless LAN
    Name                   : Lenovo
    Control options        :
        Connection mode    : Connect automatically
        Network broadcast  : Connect only if this network is broadcasting
        AutoSwitch         : Do not switch to other networks
        MAC Randomization  : Disabled

Connectivity settings
---------------------
    Number of SSIDs        : 1
    SSID name              : "Lenovo"
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : [ Any Radio Type ]
    Vendor extension          : Not present

Security settings
-----------------
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Security key           : Present
    Key Content            : not_your_network

Cost settings
-------------
    Cost                   : Unrestricted
    Congested              : No
    Approaching Data Limit : No
    Over Data Limit        : No
    Roaming                : No
    Cost Source            : Default
```

Is there any way to work with networks with SSID containing whitespaces.

Also, I don't have access to the router so I cannot change the SSID.

Comment: If the SSID contains spaces you have to use quotes around the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use quotes for SSIDs having spaces.

Example: if your WiFi's name is WiFi Hotspot, write it in the command as "WiFi Hotspot".

Answer (score 1):

While using Netsh use "*" in place of whitespace

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`netsh wlan show profiles name="NAME OF NETWORK" key=clear`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).